# Referencing a workbook name

Tags: excel, vba

I am a VBA newbie and I have created a new workbook with the following code

```
    Dim newWBname As String

    'Create a new workbook

    newWBname = InputBox("Please enter a name for the file exported.")
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Aname
```

I would like to copy my previous data from another workbook to this new workbook but I am not sure how to call the name, as the name is based on user's input. (i.e. the ? marks in the following codes)

```
Dim range1 as range

With Workbooks("Report").Worksheets("Summary")  'previous workbook
        Set range1 = .Range("A1:B" & .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        range1.Copy
        Workbooks("????").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Paste
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A Workbook Reference

**Highlights**

- You have to use `"Report.xlsm"`.
- You can `copy` in many ways.
- You have to use `PasteSpecial` instead of `Paste`.
- If you only need values, I would strongly suggest the `3rd` solution in
  the code.

**The Code**

```
Sub createWorkbookAndCopyData()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim newWBname As String
    Dim range1 As Range

    'Create a new workbook
    newWBname = InputBox("Please enter a name for the file exported.")
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    wb.SaveAs Filename:=newWBname, _
      FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook ' or xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With Workbooks("Report.xlsm").Worksheets("Summary")  'previous workbook
        Set range1 = .Range("A1:B" & .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
    With range1
'        ' Solution 1
        .Copy
        ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
        ' If you only need values then ...
        ' Solution 2 (only values)
'        .Copy
'        ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        ' or my favorite:
        ' Solution 3 (only values)
        ' Note: There is no ".Copy"
'        ws.Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a reference to the new workbook as below:

```
Dim WBnew as Workbook
Dim range1 as range
Dim newWBname As String
Dim LastRow As Long


    'Create a new workbook

    newWBname = InputBox("Please enter a name for the file exported.")
    Set WBnew = Workbooks.Add()
    WBnew.SaveAs Filename:=newWBname

With Workbooks("Report").Worksheets("Summary")
    Workbooks("Report").Worksheets("Summary").activate
    LastRow = Cells.Find("*", Range("A1"), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row
    x = Range("A1:B" & LastRow).Value
End with
With WBnew
    WBnew.activate
    Range("A1:B" & LastRow).Value = x
End with
```

Comment: I still encounter an error (Object doesn't support this property or method (Error 438)) after modifying the code, could you explain why there is such error. @Ricardo van den Bogaard

Comment: It is because of the paste method you used, replacing that line with below code will work: WBnew.Worksheets("Sheet1").Paste

Comment: As I would like to paste other data as well, the WBnew.Worksheets("Sheet1").Paste will cause the data to be overlapped. Can I specify the range without encountering any errors? @Ricardo van den Bogaard